# One "Create User For Login" - For Multiple Stand-Alone Machines

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I've created a post-deploy script for a database project in VS, in which I am granting a Windows account "UserX" user access to a database. This post-deployment script is being used by multiple developers who need to have this "UserX" granted access on thier own machines qcnb01, qcnb03,qcnb04, etc.. (with stand-alone sql instances). Is there a way to substitute [qcnb02\UserX] with a placeholder, i.e. [qcnb??\UserX], and then insert the machine name accordingly?

Below is my create user statement.

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'qcnb02\UserX')
CREATE USER [UserX] FOR LOGIN [qcnb02\UserX] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

Let me clarify that "UserX" is the static portion and the post-deploy script is actually looking for and inserting the machine name (qcnb??) back into the post-deploy script (i.e. [qcnb25\UserX]) during build\deploy time. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for your help.

JDA

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @MachineName VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @MachineName = Host_Name()
 DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N''+@MachineName+'\UserX') 
BEGIN 

    SET @SQL = 'CREATE USER [UserX] FOR LOGIN ['+ @MachineName+'\USERX] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]' 
    EXECUTE @SQL
END
```

Comment: When running this 'as is' I get...Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Windows NT user or group '@MachineName\UserX' not found. Check the name again.

Comment: Is there somkething I'm missing?

Comment: Jothish, thanks for your help. It spurred me on to get it right. Here's what worked...

Comment: DECLARE @MachineName VARCHAR(100) 
SET     @MachineName = Host_Name() 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000) 

--IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.syslogins WHERE name = N''+@MachineName+'\UserX')  

BEGIN  
    SET @SQL = 'CREATE USER [UserX] FOR LOGIN ['+@MachineName+'\machine] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]'  
    EXECUTE (@SQL)
END

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MachineName VARCHAR(100) 
SET     @MachineName = Host_Name() 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000) 

--IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.syslogins WHERE name = N''+@MachineName+'\machine')  

BEGIN  
    SET @SQL = 'CREATE USER [machine] FOR LOGIN ['+@MachineName+'\machine] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]'  
    EXECUTE (@SQL)
END
```